# Extract Raster Value around point on QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, csv, color, radius

I'm using QGIS and I'm triyng to extract raster values around some points that were created from a .csv file.

I already could extract the raster values in each point but each point represents an antenna and so I need to extract the raster values around each point, for example, the majority of color in a given radius.

Can I do this with different radius around each point, with this radius also uploaded in the .csv file and extract the values of the majority color around each point also to a .csv? If not what is the best I can do ?

This is how the map looks like .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Buffer the points to create polygons with specified radius
2. [Zonal Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalstatisticsfb) or [Zonal Histogram](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalhistogram), depending of what kind of output you want

[image]